# Why is my MVC controller action having trouble saving items to a List<>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello for some reason I'm able to add items to a list in one Action method but whenever I pass the list to a view in another method the list appears to be EMPTY. Why is this and could someone explain this? Why is the list empty when it has been added something in another method before?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Hotel.Models;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace HotelTwee.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public List<Hotel> preOrders = new List<Hotel>();


        public IActionResult Index()
        {    
            // List Count is ZERO here
            return View(preOrders);
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Hotel order)
        {
            preOrders.Add(order);
            // List COUNT is ONE here
            return RedirectToAction("Index", preOrders);               
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Removing RedirectToAction and using return View("Index", preOrders) has fixed the problem

Comment: Your controller is instantiated for every request, it doesn't keep any state.

Comment: But I have to use a list for my excercise. How can I use List instead of a Database, in this case, without having it within the controller?

Comment: Save the data to a persistent medium (ex : database) and read it again in the Index action.

Comment: making the list `static` would solve your problem, however that is probably not a good idea for concurrency reasons

Comment: the point of an exercise is to learn; look at the docs and the infinite number of tutorials available and see how people do this sort of thing instead of coming here for a solution

Comment: You can use TempData to transfer data. Take a look [How do I include a model with a RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209191/how-do-i-include-a-model-with-a-redirecttoaction/11209320#11209320)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I maintain ModelState with RedirectToAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279665/how-can-i-maintain-modelstate-with-redirecttoaction)

Comment: Not intentionally Bernard.

Comment: Keep in mind that, [you cannot pass  complex objects  in TempData in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47169878/40521)

Comment: @Shyju Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> RedirectToAction returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action.

So the state of your controller/view is gone.

Also, the second parameter of RedirectToAction is intended for the routeValues.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx